# Inversion tactics in coq

Tags: coq

Following hypothesis can be helpful in closing the
goal? Simpl inversion H2 does not work.

```
   H1:f1 (length (a :: l))=0.
   H2: false = true ->
   f1 (length (a :: l))=0.
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your goals window: it should say something like `1 subgoal, <your hypotheses here> ,_________<long horizontal line>_______(1/1),<your goal here>`.  Right now it's not clear to me what your hypotheses are and what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Post your code: everything that's needed for the question, including all definitions, the goal you want to prove, and your proof so far. What you posted here doesn't make sense on its own. All I can tell is that a hypothesis of the form `false = true -> …` won't help you in any way.

Answer (score 1):

`H2` is a function type, not an inductive type. You can only do inversion on inductive types.

Also, you `H2` is useless, since it can only be used if you have a proof of `false = true` (in which case you can already prove any theorem you want).